# Excel formula to calculate percentage with 3 options

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sales person on variable commission depending on amount sold. So basically I'm trying to put in a formula that gives me the answer to this all in one cell -

```
Sum of  1570 or under = nil 
    between 1571 - 4600 = x 6.5 %       
    above 4601 = x 7.5%
```

I have been trying myself but I'm getting nowhere. How can I accomplish this? It is a tiered solution they don't get single percentage on the whole amount.

Thanks
Anne

Comment: Please share the formula are you using now. That way we can see what you are working with and what isn't working for you.

Comment: Problem is I really haven't got a formula! I really am very low level in excel and sometimes I can just work things out myself and I've tried to with this but I haven't got a clue really!

Comment: Are these integer values (e.g. number of things sold)? If not, the list of criteria is missing what happens from 1570-1571, and from 4600-4601

Comment: Also, are the percentages tiered, or the same percentage is applied to the entirety of the sum?

Comment: So you have total sales in a given cell (say A1) and you want the commission calculated in another cell (say B1) using the given criteria, is that correct?

Comment: Ok so a sales person has to get revenue over 1570 to get commission, if they sell between 1571- 4600 they get 6.5% of that and then anything over that is 7.5% - so e.g. 5500 gives you 3029 at 6.5% and 900 at 7.5%, so £264.39 total commission - does that make sense?

Comment: Yes CharlieRB that is exactly what I'm trying to - with 3 different options/criteria so that's causing me problems!

Comment: Hi Alex they are tiered

Comment: Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/876206/edit) your question to include all of the relevant information.

Comment: Hi - have I got the question correct now?. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the tiered formula:

```
=IF(SUM(A1:A10)>4600,(SUM(A1:A10)-4600)*0.075 + 3029*0.065, IF(SUM(A1:A10)>1570,(SUM(A1:A10)-1570)*0.065, 0))
```

Some explanations:

1. First, check if sum is 4600 or above. If yes, the amount above 4600 is paid at 7.5% rate. And since the sum is above 4600, the middle criteria must apply as well, so 3029*6.5% is also added.
2. If the first step isn't true, we check if the sum is above 1570. If yes, the amount above 1570 is paid at 6.5% rate.
3. Finally, nil if 1570 or under

Comment: That is fantastic - Thank you so much and i understand the explanation as well! Do I need to click on anything else to say thanks??

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `LOOKUP` function to avoid the nested `IF` statements.

```
=SUM(A1:A10)*LOOKUP(SUM(A1:A10),{-9E+99,1571,4601},{0,0.065,0.075})
```

Using `-9E+99` instead of just `0` is probably overkill unless your sales people routinely *lose* you money but it's technically more robust.

---

**UPDATE BASED ON OP'S COMMENTS ABOUT TIERED COMMISSION**
The simplest one-line formula I can think of is:

```
=(MAX(0,MIN(SUM(A1:A10),4600)-1571)*0.065)+((MAX(0,SUM(A1:A10)-4600)*0.075))
```

I made this match your example. However, I think that it should be either `1570` & `4600` or `1571` & `4601`. How it is matches exactly how you say you do it, though.

Comment: Oh and this one works as well - brilliant. I wish I know what I was doing with formulas! Must look for a course to do. Thanks so much